# Form does not send email after submitting data. phpmailer

Tags: php, mysql, email, mysqli, phpmailer

This is updated.

On my website I have a form for people to submit data to a mysql database.
But I would like to know how I can recieve an email when someone submits something new.

I've been trying to find a solution  but I need some help.

I have a different contact form where I use phpmailer so I know that works.

It does send the data to the mysql database but it will not send me an email.

HTML:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="t3.js"></script>

<form action='t2.php' method='post' id="form1">
<div id = "container">  

    <h3>Basic Information</h3><br>

     <div id="main">

    <p><small>Name:</small><input type='text' id="name"       name='name' /><br><br><br>

    <p><small>Email:</small><input type='text' id="email"      name='email'  /><br><br><br>

    <p><small>Comments:</small><textarea  id='comments' name='comments'  rows="5" cols="40"  placeholder="Comments"></textarea> <br><br><br>

    <input type='hidden'  name='action'  value='create' />
   <p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Email Us!" /></p>
    <input type="reset"   name='reset'   value="Reset" class="reset-org"/>
    <ul id="response" />

</div> 
</form>
```

Javascript t3.js:

```
$(function() {
// These first three lines of code compensate for Javascript being turned on and off. 
// It simply changes the submit input field from a type of "submit" to a type of "button".

var paraTag = $('input#submit').parent('p');
$(paraTag).children('input').remove();
$(paraTag).append('<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Email Us Now!" />');

$('#main input#submit').click(function() {
    $('#main').append('<img src="img/ajax/contact/ajax-loader.gif" class="loaderIcon" alt="Loading..." />');

    var name = $('input#name').val();
    var email = $('input#email').val();
    var comments = $('textarea#comments').val();


$.ajax({

        url: 't2.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#form1').serialize(),
        success: function(results) {
            $('#main img.loaderIcon').fadeOut(1000);
            $('ul#response').html(results);
           }

});
});
})
```

Php: t2.php

```
<?php

$name        =$_POST['name'];
$email       =$_POST['email'];
$comments    =$_POST['comments'];

$action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : "";

if($action=='create'){ //the the user submitted the form

$query  = "insert into testdb 
            set
                name = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."', 
                email = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."',
                comments = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['comments'])."'";


if( $mysqli ->query($query) ) {
    //if saving success
    echo "User was created.";


require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php'; //replace with path to PHPMailerAutoload.php
$mail = new PHPMailer;



$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = '****';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->Port = ***; // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '*****';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '*****!';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                        // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = $email;
$mail->FromName = $name;
$mail->AddAddress('****,  'Info');  // Add a recipient
$mail->AddReplyTo($email, $name);       



$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';

$mail->Send();

}

else{
//if unable to create new record
echo "Database Error: Unable to create record.";
}

//close database connection
$mysqli->close();
}

?>
```

Comment: This line `set name = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."',` needs a double quote and semi-colon at the end, not a comma. Plus I doubt you can use `SET` with an `INSERT` however I could be wrong. But your query ending syntax is invalid.

Comment: @ Fred -ii- The code itself works. People can submit there data and it shows up in my mysql table. I only need to know how I can both submit the data to the database and send an email using phpmailer.

Comment: Even while using this `($_POST['name'])."',` with the comma at the end?

Comment: And to answer your question, you can use PHPmailer or PHP's `mail()` function right under your query, if query is successful. In place or underneath `echo "User was created.";` Once you have a successful `echo`, you can do pretty much anything.

Comment: @ Fred -ii- I minified my code so it is more people can read it better.  $query  = "insert into organisation  The next line:  name = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."',  And then the last name is: extra  = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['extra'])."'"; So I use the ; there.

Comment: Ok, I understand. See my edited comment above. I added something to my comment.

Comment: It's always best to indicate that to people by the way, about minifying your code as an example. `symcbean` made a reference to the code you posted, so that may lead people to downvoting his answer (am assuming he's a "he"), or anyone else who sees your posted code. Just thought you'd need to know this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) installed, you can do this (edit to match your info):

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php'; //replace with path to PHPMailerAutoload.php

$action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : "";

if($action=='create'){

$query  = "insert into organisation 
          set name = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."', 

$data       =$_POST;
$name       =$data['name'];

if( $mysqli ->query($query) ) {
    //if saving success
    echo "User was created.";
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'jswan';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('josh@example.net', 'Josh Adams');  // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = $name + ' was Registered';
$mail->Body    = '<b>' + $name + '</b> was registered.  Congrats on the new recruit!';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
}else{
    //if unable to create new record
    echo "Database Error: Unable to create record.";
}
```

It would've helped if you had read the `readme` [here.](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer)

Answer (score 0):

You say you are trying to send an email when your script receives a post, you've shown us lots of code, the one thing it does do is attempt to send an email. As Fred ii says, there's basic syntax errors which you need to learn how to identify and fix. The code you've shown us here code **will not work**.

Sending mail from PHP is amazingly trivial:

```
mail('user@example.com','this is the subject', 'this is the body of the email');
```

However configuring a working MTA is a lot harder - and how that integrates with PHP depends on the operating system. It's all [well documented in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php).

Certainly if you want to send anything more complicated than simple 7-bit ascii text then using a tool like swiftmailer or phpmailer will make life a lot less painful - but it still requires working integration with your MTA - hence get mail() working first.

Comment: Thanks for the mention, however it seems that the [OP's code was "minified"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927392/send-email-after-submitting-data-using-phpmailer#comment31422714_20927392) and is in fact using code that works. [I made a comment to the affect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927392/send-email-after-submitting-data-using-phpmailer#comment31422883_20927392)

Comment: Like Fred said, it is a working code. I know what you mean though, and it is hard work. I have been trying to get esmtp/mailx/xmail installed on my server for a month with no luck. (your link was the first thing I checked) Phpmailer worked so I was very happy with that. Anyway, thanks for you reply.